# Splitting text into an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to split text (convert to array) in my text area (inputbox div) and show them in div id named result?

```js
var txtBox = document.getElementById("inputbox");
var lines = txtBox.value.split("\n");
// print out last line to page
var blk = document.getElementById("result");
blk.innerHTML = lines[lines.length - 1];
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="singleQuote"></div>
<div id="inputbox" style="width: 710px;color: #ffffff;background: activecaption">
  On the other hand,
  <br/>we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of
</div>
```

Comment: please be more verbose, most of us will probably not be able to understand your issue.

Comment: from what I can tell from your JS you're trying to break up the textbox content by new lines. I see 2 issues with this. 1: it wont split anything unless you or a user actually puts new lines in there, and 2: it can't read the property `split` of `undefined` which usually means the element can't be read. Check the value's object class. From what I understand `split` only works with strings of text.

Comment: doc reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: `div` has no `value`, it has `innerHTML` and `textContent`.

Answer (score 1):

please review this one. you need to change `value` to `innerText`. it is because you're accessing `div` not `input`

```js
var txtBox = document.getElementById("inputbox");
var lines = txtBox.innerText.split("\n");
// print out last line to page
var blk = document.getElementById("result");
blk.innerHTML = lines[lines.length - 1];
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="singleQuote"></div>
<div id="inputbox" style="width: 710px;color: #ffffff;background: activecaption">
  On the other hand,
  <br/>we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of
</div>
```

Comment: this is inline with what i thought was happening. when the object is empty split can't be used :p

Comment: agree with you @KyleL, it is nothing to split if its undefined :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are trying to split on `\n` instead of `\n\r` or `\r\n` ...
Another strange thing, is that only works for `innerText` ;)

```js
var txtBox = document.getElementById("inputbox");
var lines = txtBox.innerText.split(/[\n\r]/g);

// print out last line to page
var blk = document.getElementById("result");
blk.innerHTML = lines[lines.length - 1];
```

```css
#result {
  background-color: green;
}

#inputbox {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="singleQuote"></div>
<div id="inputbox">
  On the other hand,
  <br/>we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of
</div>
```

Comment: It is strange thing, that you're trying to split HTML by Windows' new-line character when you should split by `br` elements. There are no `br` elements within `innerText` though, which also is a non-standard property, and is not supported by most of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use **split()** javascript function.

For Example

```
str = "abc\ndef";
console.log(str.split("\n"));
```

will print out

```
["abc", "def"]
```